# Specify field to apply .css style

Tags: css, column, cewp, syntax

I have a field in SharePoint list. I am trying to apply a background color in the display form. Name of field is `Process Instruction`.

I am having trouble with the `.css` syntax. It Works fine in IE Developer, but I can't translate into working `.css` in the CEWP.

How would I apply the style using `.css`?

[image: DOMpicture]

Answer (score 0):

Add a new content editor webpart and use following

```
<style>
   #SPFieldNote {
      background-color:red;
   }
</style>
```

Update

```
<style>
   #SPFieldNote:nth-child(2) {
      background-color:red; /*Assuming the element in question appears 2nd in order*/
   }
</style>
```

Comment: #SPFieldNote is a field type and applies the background to 4 other fields in addition.  How do I specify just the single field (Process Instruction) for the style?

Comment: We need to somehow identify the correct element. You can probably use the `nth:selector`. See updated answer.

Comment: nth selector not doing the job...doesn't apply to any single field no matter the value used; still searching for way to apply style to an individual field.